# Prevent transformer.transform( source, result ) from escaping special character

Tags: java, xml

I'm updating node and text content of the xml using DOM parser. To save that DOM parser I'm using transformer.transform method. 
Below is the sample code.

```
String xmlText = "<uc>abcd><name>mine</name>efgh\netg<tag>sd</tag></uc>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlText));
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inStream);
        Node node = document.getDocumentElement();      
        node.normalize();
        NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
        for(int i=0; i<childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            if(childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                System.out.println(childNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
                childNodes.item(i).setTextContent("123>");
            }
        }
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "US-ASCII");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource( document );
        OutputStream xml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult( xml  );

        transformer.transform( source, result );
        String formattedXml = xml.toString();
        System.out.println(formattedXml);
```

Since my updated document is having text content like ">", transformer.transform method is changing it to &g t;
Is there a way to get the output without escaping special characters. 
I can't use other parser because of some project constraints.
I can't use StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(). The reason is xml can have &g t;. If i use this utility method, &g t; which was originally present in the xml will also get changed.
So i want a mechanism which will not escape any special character.

Comment: Failing to escape certain special characters would potentially lead to illegal (i.e. not "well formed") XML.

Comment: @Henry: That's certainly true for `&lt;`, but I'm not sure that `&gt;` ever *has* to be escaped. That said, whatever's processing the output *shouldn't* care...

Comment: @krishna is this type of output ok for you..<uc><![CDATA[123>]]>
<name>mine</name><![CDATA[123>]]>
<tag>sd</tag>
</uc>

Answer (score 0):

The transformer you create with

```
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
```

is initialized with a default stylesheed that implements the identity transformation. That means it will simply serialize your DOM to a well-formed XML document. Output escaping is automatically applied where necessary.

If you want better control over the output, and possibly generate something that does not adhere to XML document structures, you can use a custom stylesheet that switches the output method to text. This way you control more of the structure but can do more mistakes in the XML area.

More information at

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer()
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-output